# Why does my overloaded casting operator not have access to private members?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading, private-members

I'm attempting to implement an overloaded casting operator on my templated `array2d` class using type `T`. So I'm to cast from `array2d<T>` to a new `array2d<E>`.

I'm able to perform the casting itself but problems arise when I try to set the casted data to the new instance of `array2d<E>`. The compiler tells me that the casting operator doesn't have access to the private members of `array2d`

Here's where I am so far (edited out unrelated code for brevity)

**array2d.h**

```
template<typename T>
class array2d {
private:
    // Member Variables
    T** data;
    size_t width, height;
public:
    // constructors, methods, etc...

    // Cast Operator
    template<typename E>
    operator array2d<E>() const;
};

// Other overloaded operators...

// Overloaded Casting Operator
template<typename T>
template<typename E>
array2d<T>::operator array2d<E>() const{
    // Create new instance
    array2d<E> castedArr(width, height);
    // Allocate memory for the casted data, then cast each element
    E** newData = new E*[castedArr.get_height()];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < castedArr.get_height(); i++){
        newData[i] = new E[castedArr.get_width()];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < castedArr.get_width(); j++){
            newData[i][j] = (E)data[i][j];
        }
    }
    // issue here, can't set data because it's private.
    castedArr.data = newData;

    delete [] newData;
    newData = nullptr;

    return castedArr;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "array2d.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// Cast Operator
    // Create an array2d<T> of
    // width = 5
    // height = 5
    // fill all elements with 42.1
    array2d<double> x(5, 5, 42.1);

    // Create a new array exactly the same as
    // x, where x is casted to int
    array2d<int> y = (array2d<int>) x;

    return 0;
}
```

This confused me as I have many other overloaded operators that can access the private members just fine using practically the exact same logic.

Why does this happen and what can I do to rectify it?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't want to `delete[] newData`.  You've assigned that data into `castedArr`, which is the new owner and responsible for deleting the pointer when it is done with it.

Comment: As I said to @lubgr , by not using `delete [] newData` will the destructor of the new instance make sure that it is deleted?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but this question is about a **conversion** operator, not a **cast** operator. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Many conversions can be done without a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a template, you don't nail down the actual type, you create a blue print for different types. `array2d<double>` and `array2d<int>` are different types, and by default, two instances of two different classes can't access their private members.

You can fix that by declaring every instantiation of `array2d` a friend class of the template `array2d`:

```
template<typename T>
class array2d {
    /* ... */

    template<class E> friend class array2d;

    /* ... */
};
```

As a side note, I'm not quite sure wheter

```
delete [] newData;
```

is a good idea. You're destroying *parts of* the resources that the new `array2d` instance is supposed to manage. If you `delete[]` that again in `array2d::~array2d()`, you'll have undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks very much, that was the solution! Unrelated side note: if I don't `delete [] newData` will the destructor for that instance take care of it?

Comment: You definitely need to implement the destructor yourself. And you need to manually `delete[]` both the "inner" per-row storage as well as the "outer" one. Just identical calls to `new[]`.